# Rails timestamps: complex order by updated_at / created_at

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a `Realty Model`, where Users can create and update their realties.

Here is some data. For simplicity I'm just showing you the time in the table. The date is given on top.

```
Date: 2013-07-01

ID | created_at | updated_at
----------------------------
 1 | 13:00:00   | 14:00:00
 2 | 15:00:00   | 15:00:00
 3 | 16:00:00   | 17:00:00

Date: 2013-07-02

ID | created_at | updated_at
----------------------------
 4 | 10:00:00   | 10:00:00
 5 | 12:00:00   | 17:00:00
 6 | 18:00:00   | 18:00:00
```

When viewing realties I want users to see the latest realties, firstly `ordered by date DESC`. So the realties created on July 2nd (`4,5,6`) should appear before the ones created on July 1st (`1,2,3`).

Now comes the tricky part:

On each specific day I want to differentiate between Realties that have been *updated after creation* (`1,3,5`) and the ones that simply got created *without an update* (`2,4,6`) while sorting them by Time.

**As a conclusion**

I'd like to have the realties firstly `ordered by date DESC`. And within that order I want to show the realties *without an update* `ordered by time DESC` **first**, followed by the realties *with an update* `ordered by time DESC`

The result would lead to `6,4,5,2,3,1`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want an `order by` like this:

```
order by date(created_at) desc,
         (case when created_at = updated_at then created_at end) desc,
         updated_at desc
```

Comment: I had to change `date(created_at)` to `date(updated_at)` and then it worked like a charm! :) Thanks allot!